# Turn page Flipbook with html but from a newsletter

Tags: javascript, html, html-email

I have success turning pages from a html link like this

```
<a href="javascript:$('#magazine').turn('page',4)">Index term</a>
```

But the thing i want to do know is go to a specific page from a newsletter.

"I'm making an html turn.js magazine, and all the news from this magazine are posted in a newsletter and i want each articles from the newsletter goes to a specific page of the magazine" i hope to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your example link didn't work, so I'm having a bit of a guess here.

I'd suggest you look into [anchor links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp). If you give a specific element/div an id of, for example "page01", you can target it in your email (or site) by using www.yoursite.com/page.html#page01 as the url.

Comment: Interesting. let me try it.

Comment: DAMN. it didn't work, Any other Suggestion?  you can see the Magazine in httP://magazine.mundofashion.mx/HTML

Comment: It's hard being that it is javascript powered. The only way I can think of is to maybe pass [parameters in the url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) that can get pulled into the javascript.

Comment: OK ...But how? you mean like it shows in this page? http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Comment: Yes. If you pass the page number you want in at the end and convert it as a variable like in the example, put that bar in place of the page number on your original page turn call